# UIWebView and 100% height web page

Tags: html, css, uiwebview

I am struggling with a problem: I have an UIWebView, that loads an url. The page contains an iFrame with width and height of 100% in both directions.
When `webViewDidFinishLoad` fires, the UIWebView looks fine..... for about a second, and then suddenly, with no good reason, the height of the web page starts to increase and the content - to get in the middle of the iFrame (which means, that the content goes off the screen)

1. Is it UIWebView problem or HTML related issue?
2. Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could see the HTML/CSS Structure to better comment.
But Try this.

This will be your CSS style Class

```
.class-name {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vw;
    }
```

Comment: sorry for the probably stupid question, but what kind of metric is `vh` ?

Comment: Its a CSS Unit, viewport-height. Takes the entire viewport height of the parent html container(div). https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/